# Select articles/items from database via link by name not id with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I couldn't figure out right definition for question, so i also could not google it properly

Lets take blog for example.
So far i have selected blog posts by id (which is Auto incremented) from database. www.example.com/posts/1 or /posts/22 etc.

Lets say the name for post is "My favorite flowers" .  I would like to make link appear www.example.com/posts/my-favorite-flowers instead of /posts/56 . It is also search friendlier, if im not wrong.

I would appreciate if someone cold provide some materials or explain concepts how to do it. I'm not asking code, just lead me to right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming urls like:

www.example.com/posts/my-favorite-flowers

or

www.example.com/posts/22

in your posts controller , just use php's [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function and use it on the uri segment to  do something like this:

```
function index(){
    $query_var = $this->uri->segment(2);
    if(is_numeric($query_var)){
        $this->your_model->get_post_by_id($query_var);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->your_model->get_post_by_link_name($query_var);
    }

    ...whatever the rest of your code is.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Database

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title TEXT UNIQUE,
body TEXT,
url TEXT UNIQUE,
);
```

Publish.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
$words = explode(' ', $string);
return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$body=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
$title=htmlentities($title);
$body=htmlentities($body);
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6); // first 6 words 
$urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);
$newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
$url=$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html'; // Final URL
// insert data
mysql_query("insert into blog(title,body,url) values('$title','$body','$url')");
}
?>
//جزء html
<form method="post" action="">
Title:
<input type="text" name="title"/>
Body:
<textarea name="body"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value=" Publish "/>
</form>
```

Article.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_GET['url'])
{
$url=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']);
$url=$url.'.html'; //link
$sql=mysql_query("select title,body from blog where url='$url'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$title=$row['title'];
$body=$row['body'];
}
else
{
echo '404 Page.';
}
?>

<body>
<?php
if($count)
{
echo "<h1>$title</h1><div class='body'>$body</div>";
}
else
{
echo "<h1>404 Page.</h1>";
}
?>
</body>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ article.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ article.php?url=$1
```